# refering to a method without creating an instance first / map a method with jQuery or any javascript map function

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, dictionary, prototype

I have this:

```
var Coords = function(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

Coords.prototype.toArray = function(){
    return [this.x, this.y];
}
```

Now I have an array of Coords object. I'd like to convert each Coords instance into an array with the toArray method.
I could write a loop, but I'd rather use $.map, as it's shorter and more readable.
Unfortunately, this:

```
return $.map(coords_array, Coords.prototype.toArray);
```

doesn't work at all. It just stops the execution.
The problem might be about how to refer to a method independently of any object. 
Any way of pointing to a method without creating an instance first?
Or to use $.map with a method?

Thanks for your insights.

EDIT: well, in fact, it doesn't stop the execution (this came from another problem) but `$.map(coords_array, Coords.prototype.toArray);` returns [null, null, null, null, null...].
I find this behavior strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
return $.map(coords_array, function(val, i) { val.toArray(); });
```

And refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) for more reference on jQuery's map function.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a solution without creating a wrapper function, but apparently there is not, so I'm going with this solution. Thanks for your time! Any idea why Coords.prototype.toArray can't be used directly?

Comment: Likely because when you try to call it like that, "this" defined in that function no longer refers to the Coords object, and np.

Comment: You're right. I thought I had read somewhere that 'this' was successively set to each instance in the list, but I was wrong about that.

Comment: Well, it still doesn't work. I now get a list like this one: [5,16,5,17,5,18,5,19] while I was hoping for [[5,16],[5,17],[5,18],[5,19]]. I really don't get what's happening.

Comment: Now I read something in the doc about $.map flattening arrays. I think I'm going to write my own map function. jQuery.map just sucks.

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking into that in a fiddle... it looks like the problem is with the actual .map function and it's not returning an array.  Have you tried underscore.js?

Comment: wow! This underscore.js library looks very useful! thanks for the tip.

Comment: np : )  If you're checking out underscore, try checking out backbone.js too.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `$.map` does not set the context (this) to the element currently being processed (like e.g. `$.each` does).

You can either go with a wrapper:

```
$.map(coords_array, function(coord) { return coord.toArray(); });
```

or extend the `toArray()` method to also work with the first argument:

```
Coords.prototype.toArray = function() {
    var self = this instanceof Coords ? this : arguments[0];
    return [self.x, self.y];
}
```

Comment: In javascript, `context` more correctly references [execution cnotext](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10). A function's `this` keyword is one component of its execution context and since it can reference any object, or nothing at all in strict mode, calling it "context" is not really appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that:

```
> $.map(coords_array, Coords.prototype.toArray);
```

doesn't work as expected is that you are passing a reference to the function to `map`, so when it's called, its `this` keyword isn't set to the instance and defaults to the global obejct (or undefined in ES5 strict mode). You should be able to do:

```
$.map(coords_array, function(item, index) {
    Coords.prototype.toArray.call(item);
});
```

so that the function's `this` is set to the instance.

#### Edit

See Jordan's answer.